# Server Side business logic and WCF RIA Services

Tags: wcf-ria-services

I've been building a Silverlight 5.0 application, and have most of the UI completed.  Now I want to move to the server side, and as data comes in, add business rules that I would only like to be on the server.  I realize that I could put stored procedures (include CLR Stored Procedures) into EF, but that does "feel" right, as I would like my EF to be solely dedicated to data retrieveal and maintenance of data from the UI.  Arguments for or against?

Would appreciate any refernce to articles where to integrat server side logic when using EF and WCF RIA Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably a lot of great examples out there, but I know the one I hooked to [this post on unit testing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2011/08/18/unit-testing-a-wcf-ria-domainservice-part-3-the-domainservicetesthost.aspx) has some clearly laid out business logic.

The general answer to your question is just to add logic directly to the operation. For example,

```
public void InsertCustomer(Customer customer)
{
  // do business logic here ...
  // do existing EF goo here ...
  // and do more business logic here ...
}
```

Comment: I've looked at your posts, and they are what I'm looking for – Thank-you!.  The only deviation is that there is some business logic and data that I DON’T want to appear on the client side model.  I have created a single EF diagram that is exposed to WCF RIA services.  How would I add additional tables to EF that do NOT get generated on the client?  I’m assuming that they would not be unless I add the [Include] attribute to the existing classes? Would you create a second EF file for just those tables?

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Tables will only show up on the client if (1) you return the entity from a query or (2) you [Include] the entity on another entity returned from a query. Just adding the tables to your model should be safe.